# input.nextLine() with a string inside a while loop

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop, user-input

I'm having a hard time to understand what really is wrong with my code. I'm not a good developer and I'm still learning so all tips are super welcome! :)

So what I am doing is to have a while loop that checks whether the user has given the Scanner a certain letter or not. If it has, the loop ends. If not, it keeps asking the question again.

My code is as follows:

```
Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String userAnswer = userInput.nextLine();
boolean isTrue = true;

     while (isTrue){
         if (userAnswer.equals("e")){
             System.out.println("Wrong, try again");
             userInput.nextLine();
         } else if (userAnswer.equals("k")) {
             System.out.println("That's right!"); 
             isTrue = false;
             break;
         }      
     }
```

It works, kinda. If the user gives answer "k" as the first answer, it prints out "That's right!" and then breaks the loop. If user gives answer "e" as the first answer, it  prints out "Wrong, try again" and gives a new line to answer again, BUT if you then write the correct letter, which is "k", it still prints out the "Wrong, try again" loop and won't jump to the "else if" statement.

How do I work my self around on this? Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: You need to process the scanner inside the loop. Otherwise you are not reading the next character that the user writes.

Comment: you need to use `userAnswer = userInput.readLine()` or your answer won't ever change.

Answer (score 5):

You have to reassign the value:

```
while (isTrue){
     if (userAnswer.equals("e")){
         System.out.println("Wrong, try again");
         userAnswer  = userInput.nextLine();
     } else if (userAnswer.equals("k")) {
         System.out.println("That's right!"); 
         isTrue = false;
     }      
 }
```

Comment: @davidxxx maybe. I have removed it

Comment: Hey that was it, amazing! Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @Grv21 If this answer helps you, feel free to accept it

Answer (score 3):

You are not assigning the user input to your `userAnswer` variable within the loop.

Change

```
userInput.nextLine();
```

to

```
userAnswer = userInput.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign the return value of `nextLine`

```
userAnswer = userInput.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

String is immutable object in Java API. So when you are reading next time you have to re-assign value.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
    String userAnswer = userInput.nextLine();
    boolean isTrue = true;
    while (isTrue) {
        if (userAnswer.equals("e")) {
            System.out.println("Wrong, try again");
            userAnswer = userInput.nextLine();
        } else if (userAnswer.equals("k")) {
            System.out.println("That's right!");
            isTrue = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```